Publishing a Spring Boot application on a production server and managing updates
I would like to ask about the experience of a production run of a Spring Boot web application, with embeded Tomcat, based on Maven or Gradle. So far I have been working with a vanilla Spring application, deployed on Tomcat, without dependencies manager, with all external jars collected in /WEB-INF/lib/.
I have a typical web application, which is primarily a multi-user web service, and which changes very often. I often change something in views (JSP files in my case), in Java classes, and in Javascript or CSS files.
I don't want to generate a new .jar file with each update, upload it to the server, and restart the application. I would like to work on the unpacked files and replace only the ones that have changed.
I can run the application in "debug" mode so that simple changes to classes will automatically load. And with changes to the external libraries (dependencies) used in my app, of course I can "reload" the application, but I'd like this to happen as quickly as possible and with the least impact on users.
How do I organize the process of updating the application on the server?
I assume that on the server I can execute, for example, an application update from SVN or GIT repository, and I can execute a Maven or Gradle script there. I would like the update to be as fast as possible, for example:

"git pull" of Java sources, views and static files
update external libraries from dependencies, eventually download new jar files and remove unused ones.
compile new classes on server
only if necessary - reload the application

Or maybe for such needs, the model of a Spring Boot application deployed on Tomcat, rather than with Tomcat embedding, is better? What are your experiences?
And the second question: in the application deployed on Tomcat, I used the convenient function of reloading the application with Tomcat Manager. This is a very fast operation, much faster than restarting the whole application. In addition, it allows you to serializate and restore all sessions.
Is such a "reload" possible in Spring Boot with embeded Tomcat?
Update
It looks like, Spring Boot Actuator is the answer to questions related to app reloading.
As for Maven:
I have read many tutorials on how to use Maven with Spring Boot.
However, they all assume that the apllication is packaged to jar or war. I work in the Eclipse IDE, and of course the IDE doesn't need to package the app and serves "unpacked" from the file system.
I have not been able to run the application through a Maven script in the same way.
Can you provide an example of a Maven or Gradle configuration file that:

updates the dependecy list and dependecies jars
compiles java classes
starts or restarts the application

I can't deal with this last point.
Eclipse on Windows fetches the dependecy to the folder "C:\Users\<user>\.m2\repository" and is able to pass the dependency list to javaw.exe via the "-classpath" parameter, for example:
javaw.exe --classpath C:\Users\<user>\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-web\3.2.5\spring-boot-starter-web-3.2.5.jar;C:\Users\<user>\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter\3.2.5\spring-boot-starter-3.2.5.jar;C:\Users\<user>\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-autoconfigure\3.2.5\spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.2.5.jar;C:\Users\<user>\.m2\repository\org\yaml\snakeyaml\2.2\snakeyaml-2.2.jar;C:\Users\<user>\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-json\3.2.5\spring-boot-starter-json-3.2.5.jar;C:\Users\<user>\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jdk8\2.15.4\jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.15.4.jar;C:\Users\<user>\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jsr310\2.15.4\jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.15.4.jar;C:\Users\<user>\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\module\jackson-module-parameter-names\2.15.4\jackson-module-parameter-names-2.15.4.jar;C:\Users\<user>\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-web\6.1.6\spring-web-6.1.6.jar;C:\Users\<user>\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-beans\6.1.6\spring-beans-6.1.6.jar;C:\Users\<user>\.m2\repository\io\micrometer\micrometer-observation\1.12.5\micrometer-observation-1.12.5.jar;C:\Users\<user>\.m2\repository\io\micrometer\micrometer-commons\1.12.5\micrometer-commons-1.12.5.jar;C:\Users\<user>\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-webmvc\6.1.6\spring-webmvc-6.1.6.jar;C:\Users\<user>\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-expression\6.1.6\spring-expression-6.1.6.jar;C:\Users\<user>\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-log4j2\3.2.5\spring-boot-starter-log4j2-3.2.5.jar;C:\Users\<user>\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-slf4j2-impl\2.21.1\log4j-slf4j2-impl-2.21.1.jar;C:\Users\<user>\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-core\2.21.1\log4j-core-2.21.1.jar;C:\Users\<user>\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-jul\2.21.1\log4j-jul-2.21.1.jar;C:\Users\<user>\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-spring-boot\2.21.1\log4j-spring-boot-2.21.1.jar;C:\Users\<user>\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-api\2.21.1\log4j-api-2.21.1.jar;C:\Users\<user>\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot\3.2.5\spring-boot-3.2.5.jar;C:\Users\<user>\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-core\6.1.6\spring-core-6.1.6.jar;C:\Users\<user>\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context\6.1.6\spring-context-6.1.6.jar;C:\Users\<user>\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-configuration-processor\3.2.5\spring-boot-configuration-processor-3.2.5.jar;C:\Users\<user>\.m2\repository\jakarta\xml\bind\jakarta.xml.bind-api\4.0.2\jakarta.xml.bind-api-4.0.2.jar;C:\Users\<user>\.m2\repository\jakarta\activation\jakarta.activation-api\2.1.3\jakarta.activation-api-2.1.3.jar;C:\Users\<user>\.m2\repository\jakarta\servlet\jsp\jstl\jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl-api\3.0.0\jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl-api-3.0.0.jar;C:\Users\<user>\.m2\repository\jakarta\servlet\jakarta.servlet-api\6.0.0\jakarta.servlet-api-6.0.0.jar;...

Where does Maven download files on a server that runs on Linux / Debian?
How to start the Spring Boot application through Maven?
Additional question: when deploying the application on Tomcat, the dependencies should be in "WEB-INF/lib/" - how then to download all the necessary jars to this folder with Maven?

You seen to be confusing two different things here. Packaging and deployment. If you are using springboot with an embedded tomcat, you can't really have what you are expecting, to be able to change the files on the server side it is a packaged application. Even not using the embbeded tomcat you need specific tools/libraries to be able to do what you expect which called hot-reload. Spring actuator is also not for this purpose. Both maven and gradle has specific plugins you can use to run the application direcly from the command line: mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.profiles=local

Above command will build the current code and run the application. But it is running it from scratch. The way you can assert the application is up and running without interruption is by either using or implementing "blue/green deployment" You should research about it.

Well, I am able to run a Spring Boot application in the Eclipse IDE without packaging it. Changes to the .jsp file, as well as simple changes to classes, load immediately if the application is run in "debug" mode.
My impression is that Eclipse doesn't do anything special - it actually runs the "javaw" program, with the appropriate parameters, classpath etc. Since Eclipse doesn't have to package the application to run it, I hope I don't have to on the server either. Since Eclipse doesn't have to package the application to run it, I hope I don't have to on the server either.

You are wrong. What Eclipse is doing is called HCR (Hot Code Replace) it is a feature of the Java Virtual Machine (JVM) that allows you to replace the bytecode of a running application without restarting it, this is integrated into Eclipse. It is important to note that HCR is not the same as hot reloading. HCR is more limited in scope and is specifically focused on updating the code while in a debugging session. And as mentioned, it is limited, depending on what you change in your application Eclipse will still restart it. Also JSP files are compiled into Java classes.

I recommend you to research about HCR as I said it is limited and in some cases can even cause the JVM to be in an inconsistent state causing your application to crash.

You're partly right: you need HCR to activate changes in classes, but you definitely don't need HCR to activate changes in JSP files. Jasper 2 in Tomcat recompiles JSPs in the background and does it very smartly.
And that's the feature I care most about using. It allows to update simple changes to views in a web app very quickly.

Besides, Tomcat Web Application Manager "reload" function is very powerfull - it's fast and if you implement serialization and deserialization of session attributes properly, it can be almost transparent to users.
